# Obvious open balls question

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and let $b \in B(a;r).$ Prove that exist an open ball centered in b contained in $B(a;r)$.

It seems obvious to me, but I cannot prove it.

My attempts so far: if $b \in B(a;r)$ then $d(a,b)<r$, now choose $s$ such that $s< d(a,b).$ Now we need to prove that if $x \in B(b;s) \Rightarrow x \in B(a;r).$ Using the triangle inequality we have that $$d(x,a) \leqslant d(x,b)+d(a,b) < r+s.$$ And I'm stucked here because I don't know how to proceed to end up with $$d(x,a) < r.$$

Notation: $B(a;r) = \{x: d(x,a) <r\}$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Comment: Your choice in $s$ is not correct. If $b$ is close to the boundary of the ball, then you can have elements in $B(b;s)$ that are not in $B(a;r)$.

Comment: @D_S has it right. Try solving the problem for a circle, say, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the answer should adapt to work in metric space.  In general the strategy of trying to work an answer out in 2D and trying to generalize the proof to any metric space is often a good first attempt for metric space probems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, choose $s < r-d(a,b)$. Then applying the triangle inequality with this correction will lead you to the desired result.